# Writing to a data-* attribute and getting it with jQuery .data()

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .data() Not Updating DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320934/jquery-data-not-updating-dom)

I am having a problem with using the on attribute. I have written a small set of methods to send api calls.

The markup is like this:

```
<div data-global-id="1318" data-action="unfollow" class="action text-as-link follow-btn btn" style="text-decoration: none;">unfollow</div>
```

and have an event capture like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.action', function(){
  var t={};
  t.args={};
  t.args.global_id=$(this).data('global-id');
  t.global_id=t.args.global_id;
  t.action=$(this).data('action');
  t.identifier=t.action + '_v2';
  alert('here is action: ' + t.action);
  api_post_v1(t);
});
```

The api_post_v1 correctly sends the call.

There is some code to handle the callback and it sets the markup to:

```
<div data-global-id="1318" data-action="follow" class="action text-as-link follow-btn btn" style="text-decoration: none;">follow</div>
```

The code for this is like:

```
$foo=$('.action[data-action=unfollow][data-global-id='+global_id+']');
$foo.attr('data-action','follow');
```

The key piece is the data-action. I'd like the call to the event handler above to say it is 'follow' but it says it is still 'unfollow'.

The sequence is the following:

1. load page, the data-action='unfollow'
2. click this, api call gets made and you are not following this user; the callback sets data-action='follow'
3. click this value again and the data-action is echoed as 'unfollow' rather than 'follow'

How could I tell jQuery to refresh the bindings of this event? I thought this was what $(document).on does.

thx

Comment: Can you show the api_post_v1 code?

Comment: pretty straightforward jquery post and then a couple of redirections for succesful callbacks into a set of view-layer functions. Wouldn't add much.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `data-*` attributes & jQuery's `.data()` method are *not* interchangeable. Use this to get it:

```
t.action = $(this).attr('data-action');
```

---

You seem to be mixing jQuery's `data` method with HTML5's `data-*` attributes. These are two different things. The only time they interact with one another is when you first call `.data` on an element.

When you make a call to `.data`, jQuery looks for any `data-*` attributes, and adds it to the `data` collection. However, **this only happens once**. Subsequent calls to `.data` will not look at the element's `data-*` attributes.

To quote [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> The `data-` attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

---

Since you're using `.attr('data-action', 'follow')` to set it, you should use `.attr('data-action')` to get it.

**Note:** `$('.action[data-action=unfollow]')` will not select an element that had the `action` set via jQuery's `.data`. Again, the two are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: thx, so got that first piece working. So, I'm a little confused - is it possible for me to select the data value the second time as I want to (ie the point you raise in the last paragraph)? like filter('data','unfollow')

Comment: @timpone - While you could use a filter, it's easier (and more efficient) to use an attribute selector. So, instead of using jQuery's `.data()` method, use `.attr('data-action')` exclusively. I've updated my answer.

Comment: cool, looks like this is working - but is what I'm doing really stupid (or cofusing) - should I change data-action to something like app-action and use attr to handle it? I know a lot of devs would frown on how I'm pushing things into the DOM this way

Comment: @timpone - I don't think what you're doing is stupid. Your code is clean, and works as expected. What more could you want ;)

Comment: thx, you clearly have (much) more experience - appreciate your advice.

Comment: what about this http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 ?

Comment: @DanielRuf - Thanks for the reference. I added it to my answer.