# jQuery .data() Not Updating DOM

Tags: jquery

It seems jQuery 1.7.2 isn't updating the DOM data attributes for me. Given the following markup:

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li data-my-key="12345">ABCDEF</li>
</ul>
```

Running the JavaScript below, I get some results I'm not expecting:

```
$('#foo li:first').data('my-key') // Returns 12345 - Expected
$('#foo li[data-my-key="12345"]') // Returns the expected <li>
$('#foo li:first').data('my-key', '54321')
$('#foo li:first').data('my-key') // Returns 54321 - Expected
$('#foo li[data-my-key="54321"]') // Returns an empty array - Not expected
```

Upon further investigation, I noticed the DOM has **not** been modified after setting a new value using the .data() function (verified with "Inspect Element" in Chrome 21.0.1180.81, Firebug 1.10.3 and Firefox 14.0.1).

The behavior is unexpected from my prospective, but is this the intended way for jQuery data to function? If so, what is the appropriate way to update data-* attributes with jQuery? Simply use the attr() function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271362/writing-in-a-new-attribute-and-making-it-active-in-jquery-1-7-using-document/12271393#12271393

Comment: @JosephSilber ehhh I really do not like your answer there...

Comment: @Neal - ehhh... OK. Why?

Comment: @JosephSilber ehhhh idk. doesn't look entirely kosher. maybe a mix of our two answers might might it better.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @JosephSilber I actually agree with Neal in that I find both of them useful. Joseph, you mention the two are not interchangeable, but I felt Neal did a better job (IMHO) of explaining why.

Comment: @senfo - IMHO, his explanation is [unintentionally] a little misleading. See [my comment on his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320934/jquery-data-not-updating-dom#comment-16535383).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('#foo li[data-my-key="54321"]')` is a **attribute** selector.

Using `.data(..)` changes the elements **properties** which you cannot select from without using a filter.

If you want to get **all** the elements with a certain property you can do this (using [`filter(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)):

```
$('#foo li').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).data('my-key') === 54321;
}); //returns all `#foo li` with data[my-key] === 54321
```

---

See here for more info: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)

Comment: @DanielRuf `prop` directly to do what?

Comment: the element (same syntax like .attr()) http://api.jquery.com/prop/  does he need filter?

Comment: @DanielRuf yes... or else how would you select all elements with the same data property?

Comment: [Well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) `.data(..)` does *not* change the element's properties. It's stored in [a special cache](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L45) (either on the jQuery object, or - if dealing with a DOM node - in `jQuery.cache`). Consequently, I don't understand how [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731) is relevant here.

Comment: well, he also just wants the first element in the code he posted ;-)