# Jquery set data attribute not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone an element and increment a counter. It's working well, except for this curiosity.

I think this code should update the data attribute in the source, but it doesn't. I've tried a few variations of the data tag:  `data('position-id')` `data("positionid")` `data('positionId')` - and others.

I can get it to work with attr, but I would like to know why the source isn't being updated with the data attribute. Also when I get the value from the cloned element, it's correctly incremented, but it just doesn't show up in source.

The markup:

```
<div class="row layout-position" data-position-id="0">
...
```

and the relevant part of the js

```
 var clone = $position.clone();
 var expression = 'layoutPositionList\\[' + currentId + '\\]';
 var expression2 = 'layoutPositionList' + currentId;
 var replacement = 'layoutPositionList[' + nextId + ']';
 var replacement2 = 'layoutPositionList' + nextId;
 var regex= new RegExp(expression, "g");
 var regex2= new RegExp(expression2, "g");
 var newHtml = clone.html().replace(regex, replacement);

 newHtml = newHtml.replace(regex2, replacement2);
 clone.html(newHtml);
 clone.find('input').val('');

 console.debug(clone);

 $position.after(clone);
 $position.after('<hr />');
 // this works
 //$(clone).attr("data-position-id", nextId);
 // this doesn't 
 $(clone).data("position-id", nextId);
```

Comment: No, jQuery.data does not update the "source", only the in-memory representation of data (which is separate from the attribute).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320934/jquery-data-not-updating-dom