# jquery use data tag selector after updating data tag on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I want to be able to get a set of elements that match a selector in jQuery. I have HTML with data tag attributes that get altered dynamically by jQuery using the .data(key, value) method.

However, after dynamically updating an element's data tag it seems I can no longer use a selector to get that element with the updated value. It still returns the old value.

I have a JSFiddle setup to demonstrate this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/o6pnvqgv/1/

Here is the example code:

```
<span id="example" data-tag="5"></span>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $example = $('#example');

    $('#result').html($example.data('tag'));
    $example.data('tag', 7);

    $('#result').html("elements that have tag 5: " + $('[data-tag="5"]').length);

    $('#result2').html("elements that have tag 7: " + $('[data-tag="7"]').length);
});
```

RESULT:

elements that have tag 5: 1
elements that have tag 7: 0

I know I can use a each loop and compare data for each individual element through an if statement.. But I want to be able to query all elements by the new set data tag value and get those results back.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered here:

[jQuery .data() Not Updating DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320934/jquery-data-not-updating-dom)

`$('#foo li[data-my-key="54321"]')` is a **attribute** selector.

Using `.data(..)` changes the elements **properties** which you cannot select from without using a filter.

If you want to get **all** the elements with a certain property you can do this (using [`filter(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)):

```
$('#foo li').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).data('my-key') === 54321;
}); //returns all `#foo li` with data[my-key] === 54321
```

---

See here for more info: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)