# Send the id of the message by clicking on the submit button

Tags: jquery, mysql

I got a question since i'm busy with a shoutbox system.
I've added a report input button (it's an image anyway), when you click on it, it have to insert the ID of the message into the database.

However, It's my first time when i create something like this and i would like to stay on the same page (so for example: www.domain.com/shoutbox.php and not www.domain.com/shoutbox.php?p=report)
I've read allready that i can use Jquery but i got no idea how to send the ID with it..

**You can view the code here: http://pastebin.com/xKP9Aymk**
*I marked the right are with "/// START REPORT AREA" and /// END REPORT AREA"*

Can anyone help me with it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have no idea how an ajax call works, and you're really so busy, just use a regular link to a script that inserts whatever you like into the DB and just returns a 204 header ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to add some code to your question (especially what you already tried) and what your _specific_ problem with this code is, as no one here will just do the work for you. At least you may add some pseudo-code, if there simply is no code to show yet, so that we get a general idea of what you want.

Comment: I need the report script for the shoutbox and i would like to stay on the same page. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put it in a data variable like this:

```
<div class='shout-btn' data-id='12'>shout</div>
```

and then something like:

```
$('.shout-btn').on('click', function(){
   var id=$(this).data('id');
   console.log(id);
   // do the rest here which would be a post; kinda a different question

});
```

Also check out the answer to this question for intermixing jQuery data functions with html5 data functions; a common source of bugs: [Writing to a data-* attribute and getting it with jQuery .data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271362/writing-to-a-data-attribute-and-getting-it-with-jquery-data) Prob not relevant to use case here though